# Extrude along mirror line

Tags: mirror

I added a mirror modifier along the X axis. Then I added some vertices on the mirrored axis. I tried to extrude a vertex along the X axis, but it didn't work. I am able to extrude along the other axes, but not along the X axis. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Does it work if you disable *Clipping* in the mirror modifier?

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you. Please write it in answer section, I will mark it as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When clipping is enabled, any geometry exactly along the mirror axis will not be allowed to move. If you disable it, then you can extrude and move center vertices.